# Problem disabling certain dropdown input fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

Am working on an application whereby I have some cards that have 
select dropdown fields. On the Cards I have written a JavaScript 
logic whereby if the user selected a wife or husband as an option 
on the any of the **cards select drop down, any of the other husband 
or wife dropdown field should add a CSS class of disabled**.

The problem is that the **CSS class is not added on other options on the cards which match husband or wife**. Basically, I want when the user selects wife or husband option on any card, all other husband or wife options on other cards should change the class to be disabled (which has pointer-vents of none).

**My code:**

```js
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu');
for (let menu of menus) {
  menu.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    var selectWife = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Wife"]');
    var selectHusband = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Husband"]');
    selectWife.forEach(function(option) {
      var change1 = option.classList.add('disabled');
      change = selectedOption === 'Wife';
    });
    selectHusband.forEach(function(option) {
      var change2 = option.classList.add('disabled');
      change2 = selectedOption === 'Husband';
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Card 1 -->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 1 -->

<!-- Card 2-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input otherMenu"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 2-->

<!-- Card 3-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 3-->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [linked question from Maaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element), you cannot style an individual `option` element (except for `color`/`background-color`). However for this use case you don't need to, `option` has a `disabled` property which does what you want: Disables selecting and fades the option.

Javascript:

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu');
for (let menu of menus) {
  menu.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    var thisMenu = this;
    var selectWife = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Wife"]');
    var selectHusband = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Husband"]');
    selectWife.forEach(function(option) {
      if(!(thisMenu === option.parentNode)){
        if(selectedOption === 'Wife'){
            option.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
    selectHusband.forEach(function(option) {
      if(!(thisMenu === option.parentNode)){
        if(selectedOption === 'Husband'){
            option.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
.other-menu option:disabled {
  color: blue;
}
```

Notes: you have `otherMenu` class incorrectly assigned incorrectly placed in your HTML, and I'd recommend having a placeholder value before a selection is made, as in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p30rqtwo/18/):

Comment: @womania  Disabling makes the value to be null,,I want the text to be disabled but the value to remain intact ..

Comment: Then you want to add readonly attribute it has the same affect as disabled but allows the value to stay intact

Comment: @Martin Changed the code to add a check - it now only disables menus other than the one selected (keeping the value intact for the menu that was selected)